# Laravel 5 multi dynamic dropdown

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, dropdown

I'm trying to use the data of the first dropdown, to fill the second.
An example here:
https://gitlab.com/Bons/laravel5.3_dynamic_dropdown/blob/master/readme.md

Controller functon return data, but second dropdown is empty.

First dropdown:

```
<span>Country: </span>
<select style="width: 200px" class="country" id="id_country">
    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">-Select-</option>
    @foreach($countries as $contry)
        <option value="{{$contry->id_country}}">{{$contry->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

linked dropdown:

```
  <label>City
        <select id="region" class="form-control input-sm" name="region_id">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </label>
```

Script:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('change','.country',function(){
                console.log("hmm its change");
                var id=$(this).val();
                console.log(id)
                $.ajax({
                    type:'get',
                    url:'{!!URL::to('findRegions')!!}',
                    data:{'id':id},
                    success:function(data) {
                        console.log("success");
                        console.log(data.length);
                        console.log(data);
                        $.each(data, function(index,subCatObj){
                        //    console.log(subCatObj.name)
                            $('#region').append(''+subCatObj.name+'');
                        });
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        console.log("error");
                    }
                });
            });  
        });  
    </script>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/findRegions/','GirlsController@findRegions');
```

Controller function:

```
public function findRegions(Request $request){
    $id=$request->id;
    $regions=Region::select('name')
        ->where('id_country',$id)
        ->get();
  dump($regions);
  return $regions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did it,
in routes/web.php

```
Route::post('select-ajax', 'Main@selectAjax')->name('select-ajax');
```

in Controller : Main.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    View::share('selectAllCountries', Country::pluck("name","id")->all());
}
public function selectAjax(Request $request)
{
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $getRegion = Region::where('id_country',$request->id)->pluck("nameOfTheRegion","id")->all();
            $data = view('ajax-select',compact('getRegion'))->render();
            return response()->json(['options'=>$data]);
        }
 }
```

then create a simple blade file name ajax-select.blade.php

```
<option selected disabled>--- Select Region---</option>
@if(!empty($getRegion))
    @foreach($getRegion as $key => $value)
        <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Ajax call

```
 {!! Form::select('country',[' '=>'--- Select Country ---']+$selectAllCountries,null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}

 {!! Form::select('region',[' '=>'--- Select Region---'],null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
<script>
    $("select[name='country']").change(function(){
         var id = $(this).val();
         var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
          $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('select-ajax') }}",
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {'id':id, '_token':token},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("select[name='region']").html('');
                        $("select[name='region']").html(data.options);
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("error!!!!");
                   }
         });
     });
</script>
```

Hope this helps